# How to print a Meson message when a target is built?

Tags: build, meson-build

In Meson, after building firmware , I have a `run_target` which prints the size of the firmware.  I'd like to print that info to the screen.  This can be done via `message` (capturing the text from `run_command`).  But I'd like to do it when, but only when, I rebuild the firmware.

How can I tell Meson: After building target X, print this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin `message()` is only for configure-time, e.g. when you run `meson setup`. You are wanting something to be done at build-time, e.g. when you're compiling and linking sources. As you noted, `run_target()` is a valid way of achieving this, but `run_target()` will only ever run when invoked by name. In general, as of meson v1.2.0 there would not be a particularly clean way of forcing this to happen, however there is a particularly hacky solution by means of `custom_target()`...

```
firmware = executable(...)
custom_target(
  'display-firmware-size',
  input:   firmware,
  output:  'firmware-size',
  command: [print_size_to_stderr, '@INPUT@'],
  capture: true # captures stdout to the file, thereby creating it
)
```

where the `print_size_to_stderr` variable is an external program like...

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
>&1 stat --printf="%s" $1
```

(command taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16644)

If you just use plain old `ninja -C <build>` or `meson compile -C <build>`, then if the firmware rebuilds, the `display-firmware-size` target is marked as needing to be rebuilt, which will print some bits to stderr, and then create a file. The file will keep the task from re-running until the firmware changes again. It's a bit gross but if this is a key thing you want, it would get you across the wire